# What is this logo image?

Tags: joomla

Can you identify the filename of the logo image (spelling "Abrax") on [this homepage](http://www.melvilletenniscentre.com.au/new/)?

I've having trouble finding it in the offline files I unzipped from the paid template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [image](http://www.melvilletenniscentre.com.au/new/components/com_gantry/images/header-assets.png) is set in CSS. If you open the image in the browser, you probably won't see anything as it's transparent with white text.

Answer (score 0):

url("../images/header-assets.png")